# Using syslog with nginx / php-fpm

Tags: drupal, ubuntu, nginx, syslog, php

I'm looking into migrating my Apache based Drupal installs, but need to have rsyslog based remote error logging.  We're using Amazon EC2, and error_log files written to instances that come and go is a bit of nightmare.  In particular, if an application hits a PHP error, we need to see those as soon as they happen.

Assuming we're using nginx and php-fpm, if I put the following into an fpm pool definition, it works:

```
error_log = /path/to/logs/error.log
```

since if I do this in PHP, it will indeed go to /path/to/logs/error.log:

```
<?php
  error_log('send this to our log');
?>
```

But if I set up the pool as

```
error_log = syslog
```

as near as I can tell, the output goes no where at all.  At least, I have yet to figure out a configuration for rsyslog.conf on Ubuntu that will receive any input for this.

What's the best way to get centralized error logging when using nginx and php-fpm?  I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, with the packaged versions of php5-fpm and nginx.

Comment: Which one are you after, php logs or nginx logs? They are different things and the way to achieve what you ask probably varies wildly between them. Bunching the two together in one question will probably reduce your chance of getting a good answer that covers both.

Answer (score 0):

nginx is unrelated here.  I would recommend the syslog module for Drupal.  Put that on and then everything goes to syslog which would go to watchdog, that catches PHP errors too.

PHP has a native syslog() function as well.

If you are using syslog-ng I think you can route the normal php log into syslog, but I've never heard of being able to do error_log = syslog.